# PoE woes with custom PSE board powering a Pi4B, is it termination?

Tags: raspberry-pi, ethernet, poe

Sorry if this is a bit long and rambling but I've been wrestling with this problem for far too long. I've designed and built a PCB that uses an STM32F767 processor and a LAN8742A as the Phy to implement a 100 Mbit Ethernet node, as close as possible to a copy of the Nucleo board as I can manage. This seems to work reliably. On the other end of the Ethernet link I'm hanging a Raspberry Pi4B with a touchscreen, which gets its power using PoE. I'm supplying 54V using a boost switcher and the TI TPS23861 to handle the PoE negotiation at the PSE end. The schematics look like this.
[image: Phy circuit with magnetics]

The specific problem I'm stuck on is that everything works separately, but in the target setup the PoE power is often (4 out of 6 Pis) clobbering the Ethernet link! I'm basing this conclusion on the fact that if I power the Pi using a 5V brick then the link works. Other observations are:

1. The problem goes with the Pis, not with my board.
2. I forgot to terminate the spare pairs but terminating them with a 75 ohm resistor made no difference.
3. Switching the power to the spare pairs (mode B instead of mode A?) makes no difference.
4. I don't have a 'chassis' so should I connect the chassis net to 0VL?

I'm really getting desperate so any suggestions are gratefully received!

Comment: Is your 54 volt boost converter an isolated output type?

Comment: Pls provide  the measurements for ripple and common mode noise to earth ground for both supplies. You seem to need better EMI design, such as filter and CM choke.

Comment: @OliverSedlacek What boost switcher? Also Are you sending 54V DC down the ethernet?

Comment: My 54V boost converter is not isolated, it's based around an LM5022. The +54V is always on and the TPS23861 drives an NMOSFET to switch the return side. At the PD end I'm using the MP8007, which is isolated. This did seem to introduce noise as I copied the Pi 'official PoE HAT' circuit, which doesn't include the CLC filter used on the MP8007 eval PCB. Adding the CLC filter seems to improve things. I haven't found a reliable way of probing the rail noise because if I clip my scope ground to the PoERet then power negotiation fails.